# How to write a method for a transposed matrix?

Tags: java

I am trying to create an application class `MatrixApplication`, in which the user first enters the number of rows and columns of the matrix.

This will be used to create an array object.
Then the elements of the `Matrix` are called up row by row and column by column. When all elements have been read in, they are assigned to the matrix object.

Next, the array is transposed and finally the transposed array is displayed.

How do I assign the elements to the Matrix object?
How do I display a transposed array?

```
package domain;

public class Matrix {

    private int[][] numbers;

    public Matrix(int rows, int columns) {
        setNumbers(numbers);
        if (rows < 1)
            rows = 1;
        else
            rows = rows;
        if (columns < 1)
            columns = 1;
        else
            columns = columns;
        numbers = new int[rows][columns];
    }

    public final void setNumbers(int[][] numbers) {
        this.numbers = numbers;
    }

    public int[][] getNumbers() {
        return numbers;
    }


    public int[][] transpose() {
        int[][] transpose = new int[numbers[0].length][numbers.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numbers[0].length; ++j) {
                transpose[j][i] = numbers[i][j];
            }
        }
        return transpose;
    }
}
```

```
package ui;

import java.util.Scanner;

import domain.Matrix;

public class MatrixApplication {
    
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter the number of rows of the matrix:");
        int rows = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("nter the number of columns of the matrix:");
        int colums = input.nextInt();

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix(rows, colums);
        
        final int[][] numbers = new int[rows][colums];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < colums; ++j) {
        System.out.printf("Enter the element of row %d and column %d: ", i + 1, j + 1);
        numbers[i][j] = input.nextInt();
                }
                  }
        }
        
                
        System.out.printf("The transposed matrix: %d",matrix.transpose());

            }
        }
```

And if I want this form of transposed matrix:
[example of a 4x2 array to a 2x4 array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAaSw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply read the numbers into a two-dimensional array and call `matrix.setNumbers`.

```
final int[][] numbers = new int[rows][colums];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < colums; ++j) {
        System.out.printf("Enter the element of row %d and column %d: ", i + 1, j + 1);
        numbers[i][j] = input.nextInt();
    }
}
matrix.setNumbers(numbers);
System.out.printf("The transposed matrix: %s", Arrays.deepToString(matrix.transpose()));
```

Comment: I adjusted my question before printing a transformed matrix. Would you like to take a look at it? Thank you.

Comment: @Leenieke19 What is the issue with the code I have provided?

Comment: If you just need to print differently, use a loop to print.